# Hibernate 5.2 and Spring 4.3, Non JPA - javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I am seeing the following error upon upgrading my application from hibernate 5.1 to 5.2.6.  Specifically, this is spring 4.3.5.

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3450)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1418)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1414)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.flush(SessionFactoryUtils.java:144)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:95)
org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:95)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:932)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:744)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy140.mapUserFromContext(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:87)
```

As you can see in the stack trace below, spring clearly has started a transaction , and is actually trying to trigger a flush before committing it's transaction.  It appears that the code that syncronizes hibernate and spring transactions is not working with hibernate 5.2 (looks to be located at the end of `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext.currentSession()`).  Is this an open bug, or am I missng a config somewhere?

Comment: Apparently it hasn't started a transaction else the exception wouldn't occur. Can you add some of your configuration? Also why would using LDAP lead to an exception with a hibernate transaction?!

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  I'm seeing the same issue (and again *definitely* have a transaction starting, note that the method `org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction` is on the call stack...).  This does appear to be a bug, but the [only related bug report I can find in Spring's JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14364) was apparently fixed and released in 4.3.3, so shouldn't be an issue here.

Comment: So, I needed to get through it, so I moved to `org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager`.  This worked as expected, allowing a single transaction to be shared across multiple datasources, though it was overkill, as we only use one datasource. Unfortunately, the `hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager` manager, suggested by @Jules, won't work for us, due to us having multiple session Factories, but it may work for you.

Comment: probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57129912/when-i-add-async-entitymanager-flush-will-raise-an-exception, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49523807/javax-persistence-transactionrequiredexception-no-transaction-is-in-progress-af

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the issue was caused by an old configuration setting using Spring's JDBC TransactionManager implementation, rather than the appropriate Hibernate-integrated one.  This was apparently acceptable for Hibernate 4.1, but not for 5.2.  The fix was to change my transaction manager bean declaration to:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem when upgrading a legacy application that is backed by Spring XML configuration.

The following hibernate properties had to be added to the Spring LocalSessionFactory configuration:

```
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class">jta</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">JBossAS</prop>
```

The reason seems to be that with Hibernate 5.2 the default value for hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class is jdbc for non-JPA applications. And that doesn't play well with Spring transactions.

Answer (score 1):

We are facing the same problem, I found the different reason for it.

Spring 4.3.9 , Hibernate 5.2.10 with XML Configuration & Declarative transaction.
Problem was setReadOnly() placed at wrong place in transaction, it sets after the getTransaction()

Code With error:

```
DefaultTransactionDefinition transactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
transactionStatus = transactionManager.getTransaction(transactionDefinition);
transactionDefinition.setReadOnly(true);  //wrongly set it will not set in transactionstatus
//DAO Call
transactionManager.commit(transactionStatus);
```

Changes in above code for fixing the issue:

```
DefaultTransactionDefinition transactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
transactionDefinition.setReadOnly(true);
transactionStatus = transactionManager.getTransaction(transactionDefinition);
//DAO Call
transactionManager.commit(transactionStatus);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same exception when we upgraded our spring-boot-dependencies bundle from 1.5 to 2.0.2 (which effectively upgrades spring 4 to 5, and hibernate 5.0 to 5.2).

I had a test case that was marked ***@Transactional*** which internally invokes an internal method that was marked ***@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)*** as it had some stuff that shouldn't be a part of the upstream transaction. Started getting the below error after the upgrade which was working fine with Spring 4 and Hibernate 5.0 combination.

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3505)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1427)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1423)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.flush(SessionFactoryUtils.java:147)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:95)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:96)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:922)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:532)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
```

It was resolved by adding 'readOnly = true' attribute to the method where a transaction wasn't needed - ***@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation=Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)***.  It appears that newer versions will  need this to indicate or serve as a hint to the calling transaction subsystem. Check [readOnly attribute](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#readOnly--) docs.

Also, do check the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41778024/hibernate-and-transactionrequiredexception-when-propagation-set-to-propagation-n) for a similar explanation.