# javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress after migrating spring/hibernate version

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

There are lot questions on this exception, but after research I believe this is not duplicate as it relates to issues after version migration on already working code.

I'm trying to migrate from Spring 4.3.9.RELEASE/ Hibernate 4.3.6.Final to Spring 5.0.4.RELEASE/ Hibernate 5.2.14.Final. The code is not changed except changing the dependencies as needed and changing package names to hibernate5 as needed. I keep getting the exception **javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress**

@Transactional attribute is applied at appropriate places. I have done lot of research to find out why especially when it applies to migration from one version to another. Following log actually shows that transaction is started, but still exception is being thrown

```
14:39:28,719 DEBUG [main] org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:55) - begin
14:39:28,719 TRACE [main] org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.begin(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:66) - Preparing to begin transaction via JDBC Connection.setAutoCommit(false)
14:39:28,719 TRACE [main] org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.begin(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:68) - Transaction begun via JDBC Connection.setAutoCommit(false)
14:39:28,719 TRACE [main] org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.afterBeginCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:150) - ResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl#afterBeginCallback
    javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3466) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) [spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) [spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
14:39:28,812 DEBUG [main] org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:98) - rolling back
14:39:28,812 TRACE [main] org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:115) - Preparing to rollback transaction via JDBC Connection.rollback()
```

Lot of debugging has led me to following function org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.isJoined() where physicalTransactionDelegate is null. Because isJoined function returns false, exception is thrown.

```
@Override
public boolean isJoined() {
    return physicalTransactionDelegate != null && getTransactionDriverControl().isActive( true );
}
```

[Edit based op comments]

It's java configuration. The code crashing is very simple. Someone has autowired a dao and calls following method. It's basically checking if the record exists in database, if it exists, update it, or create a new one.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void registerApplication(final ApplicationType type, final Class<?> versionedClass, final String extraData) throws Exception {
    final Properties pr = getVersionInformation(versionedClass);
    final String commit = pr.getProperty("git.commit.id");
    if (commit == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Could not find property git.commit.id");
    }
    VersionInfo info = extraData == null ? findBy(type, commit) : findBy(type, commit, extraData);
    if (info != null) {
        log.info("Found entry for the version, just updating usage count");
        info.incrementUsageCount();
    } else {
        info = new VersionInfo();
        info.setApplicationType(type);
        info.setCommitId(commit);
        info.incrementUsageCount();
        info.setExtraData(extraData);
    }
    save(info);
    log.info("Saved version information for {}:{}:{}", type, commit, extraData);
}
```

What should I change in my code to make it work again?

Comment: The problem could be with your spring contexts

Comment: can you share bit of your configuration, where you are scanning your packages for services, repositories, controllers and beans related to db

Comment: @kakabali, what you said could be right, but then it does not explain autowiring does work and same code worked in previous version, I'm able to read the data etc. Moreover the log says it has created transaction

Comment: can you share the bit of code where it is getting raised from your code?

Comment: are you using xml configuration? or java configuration?

Comment: well I updated recently too, and I am not getting no exception like this, so it might be some configuration issue only, that must have changed for you after the upgrade may be

Comment: I upgraded spring from  **4.3.2.RELEASE** to **5.0.3.RELEASE** and hibernate from **4.2.6.Final** to **5.2.10.Final**, if you want I can try your hibernate version also but it should not be much different

Comment: I noticed they have released one more version of hibernate. Let me try with that one first and then I'll try your version

Comment: Which transaction manager are you using? Do you have the spring-orm module as a dependency - it provides the integration between Spring and Hibernate?

Comment: Take a look at the transactions part of the migration guide https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/migration-guide.adoc#transactions -  there was a new level of indirection introduced and now in version 5 you?/Spring? have to specify the hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class setting - if this is not specified a default behavior kicks in, which might lead to this error you're seeing.

Comment: @kakabali, One problem solved. I traced the problem to subtle changes in spring behavior which ends up using different bean than the one it should be using. I am trying to formulate exact scenario, but it has to do with multiple configurations and some of the configurations dynamically loaded. I still have same exception, but now much more down the line. At least I know what to look for now.

Comment: @hovanessyan, thanks for the pointers. It did help to understand the underlying changes more.

Comment: @user871199 great to hear that. so multiple configs means multiple contexts?

Comment: @kakabali, both actually. We have 50 odd projects. Runtime is aware of 40 or so by importing configuration. Loading of other is decided at runtime based on properties. This ends up creating another context when needed.

Comment: so my answer The problem could be with your spring contexts was correct in the case, :-)

Comment: same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57129912/when-i-add-async-entitymanager-flush-will-raise-an-exception

Comment: I am facing the same exception. Were you able to resolve this?