# Spring 5 Hibernate 5 transaction issue

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I am working first time with transactions. Any pointers/help would be highly appreciated.

I have seen few similar queries but that did not help

I have Spring 5 Hibernate 5 set up with Spring HibernateTransactionManger.
Issue comes when a method marked with @Transactional completes. Based on debugging, I know that inside JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl isJoined method, physicalTransactionDelegate, instance of TransactionDriverControlImpl is null (at start of transaction it is instantiated). I am trying to figure out what condition/code is make it null because of which no transaction is in progress exception comes.

Please share if more info is needed

Comment: probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57129912/when-i-add-async-entitymanager-flush-will-raise-an-exception, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49523807/javax-persistence-transactionrequiredexception-no-transaction-is-in-progress-af