# When I add @Async, entityManager.flush() will raise an exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I'm using Spring framework.

The structure of my project is **Controller ➡️ Service ➡️ Logic**.

I added `@Transactional` in Logic class. I am using EntityManager to do DB operations. After every db operation(select, update...), I am calling `entityManager.flush()` method.
Everything is fine.

But in order to improve performance, I added `@Async` in Service class.
Then an exception is raised when I am calling `entityManager.flush()`.

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3505)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1427)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1423)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy150.flush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:305)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy150.flush(Unknown Source)
```

I debugged the source and found that EntityManager is bound to thread by using ThreadLocal, but when I added @Async, there will be a new thread, this new thread will create a new EntityManager, that is OK. But when I call entityManager.flush(), it will check Transaction and call `JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.isJoined()` method,`physicalTransactionDelegate` is null, so the exception will be raised.

**`physicalTransactionDelegate` is initialized in main thread.**

What should I do if I want to execute entityManager.flush()? Or is my understanding  about the source wrong?

Controller.java

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getTest", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public ResponseDto execute(@Valid final RequestDto requestDto) {
        List<CompletableFuture<Dto>> completableFutures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ItemRequestDto item : requestDto.getItemRequestDtoList()) {
            completableFutures.add(service.execute(item));
        }
    }
```

Service.java

```
@Async("taskExecutor")
    public CompletableFuture<InventoryInfoListDto> execute(final ItemRequestDto item) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(logic.execute(item));
    }
```

Logic.java

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable.class, timeout = 60)
public ResponseDto execute(final ItemRequestDto item) {
    // process...
}
```

**I created an issue in github.**
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23325

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
Just add `entityManager.joinTransaction()`;.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug.

- With No @Async

  - When request comes, `TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource((Object key, Object value)` will be called, and a new EntityManager will be bound to current thread.
  - Then, `EntityManagerFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf, @Nullable Map<?, ?> properties, boolean synchronizedWithTransaction)` is called to get the bound EntityManager. Inside this method, it will call `EntityManager.joinTransaction()`.  This method will call `JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.getTransactionDriverControl()` to initialize `TransactionDriverControlImpl physicalTransactionDelegate`.
  - When we call `EntityManager.flush()`. `JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.isJoined()`will be called to check.
- With @Async

  - When request comes, `TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource((Object key, Object value)` will be called, and a new EntityManager will be bound to current thread.
  - If there is a @Async, a new thread will be created.
  - Then, `EntityManagerFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf, @Nullable Map<?, ?> properties, boolean synchronizedWithTransaction)` is called to get the bound EntityManager. But in this new thread, there is no bound EntityManager, so a new one will be created, **but `EntityManager.joinTransaction()` will not be called. So `TransactionDriverControlImpl physicalTransactionDelegate` will not be initialized.**
  - **When we call `EntityManager.flush()`. Since `TransactionDriverControlImpl physicalTransactionDelegate` is null, an exception will be raised.**

Why `EntityManager.joinTransaction()` is not called when a new EntityManager is created in a new thread?

Comment: same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49523807/javax-persistence-transactionrequiredexception-no-transaction-is-in-progress-af